# Show different content depending on the country of visitor

Tags: seo, google, search

I want to have results from lots of different countries stored in my database. Then I want to grab the country code of the visitor and only show them the results from their country.

For example if they are in the UK, when they visit my site they will only see results of items which were posted in the UK.

My concern with this is I am showing different content to different users and I'm not sure what the SEO implications are of this. Is there anything to be worried about, or should I forward users to a country specific sub domain or extension?

This is the best information I can find on it:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html

Comment: The mechanism you are suggesting is likely to be seen as cloaking by search engines.

Comment: @closetnoc Do you think redirecting is better then? I.e Google.com to google.co.uk

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You cannot control which Google site or data center that a search user comes from. Your site will be in several and none of them will necessarily indicate the users language. Please understand that Google checks your site from outside of their network and has for a very very long time to defeat cloaking. If there is a significant enough of a difference, you could be de-listed. Most sites either use a directory or sub-domain for language. Some do redirect based upon locale, but not make one site appear as several. Do not redirect Google or Bing.

Comment: Google was just an example, im saying when you visit google.com and you are in the uk it sends you to google.co.uk. I'm not trying any black hat, im just trying to make the results revelant to the country which the user visits. If my way is wrong, please tell me what you suggest.

Comment: Okay. I get it. I was just warning you about search engines. There are people who have done this. The how to do it is not something I have followed so I have no idea on what you need to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users are now confident seeing TLDs of their country, or seeing the name of it after the .com

```
example.com/france
example.fr
```

Are two good example.
In the first case, you can have an "homepage" where you let people choose their country. Then, the country real homepage in the subdirectory would be the one you optimize for country specific visitors (and Google is very good in understanding gerarchical structure of websites).
Also, don't forget to target even for languages using html markup in `<head>`, or even using subdirectories when necessary like in Canada:

```
example.ca/fr
example.ca/en
```

If you can, try also to have your server IP near the targeting location. But it could be expensive, so just having a server in the right continent for targeting location is already good.

You can then say to Google and Bing through their respective Webmaster Tools how to geotarget your site.

That's all you need to do. Don't take action based on server data before the user, or even worst trying to manipulate Google.

Here you can see what Google and Bing themself suggest https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/geo-targeting-your-website-b7629197